# adding boolean field with default value on a large postgres table

Tags: performance, postgresql

We have a very large table (1 Million records) in some cases and we need to add boolean fields to it which have default values.
If we add only column it takes 3 minutes and we add 3 columns in the same statement it takes same time.

```
$ALTER TABLE Job ADD COLUMN test BOOLEAN NOT NULL default false;
ALTER TABLE
Time: 186506.603 ms

    $ALTER TABLE Job ADD COLUMN test BOOLEAN NOT NULL default false , 
    ADD COLUMN test1 BOOLEAN NOT NULL default false, 
    ADD COLUMN test2 BOOLEAN NOT NULL default false;
    ALTER TABLE
    Time: 179055.546 ms
```

We are on Postgres 9.1 . Is there a postgres feature allows to add multiple boolean fields with default values in one shot? This is for a database change management /upgrade solution . Is it better than using temp table to copy and insert to add multiple boolean fields with default values to a table ? The temp table approach is described in this blog:
http://blog.codacy.com/2015/05/14/how-to-update-large-tables-in-postgresql/

Comment: "Is there a postgres feature which makes this happen?"  I don't understand this question.

Comment: Makes _what_ happen? (by the way: 1 million rows is far from being "very large")

Comment: When we update a value in a column, Postgres writes a whole new row in the disk, deprecates the old row and then proceeds to update all indexes. This is equivalent to an INSERT plus a DELETE for each row . So in this case we are adding 3 boolean fields , Is Postgres adding these fields in one shot? It should be faster to create a new table from scratch than to update every single row. Sequential writes are faster than sparse updates. I have implemented a solution using temp table but with this feature , I think there is no need for such a solution

Answer (score 5):

You've already shown the best (simple) way - a compound `ALTER TABLE` statement that adds them all at once.

To do it without a long lock, you have to do it in multiple steps. Add the column as nullable without the default. Add the default but leave it nullable. `UPDATE` all existing rows to add the new value, preferably in batches. Then finally alter the table to add the `not null` constraint.

Comment: This is a hassle to do, but sadly the only reliable way to avoid locking the table for a long time.